# Mp3-player in Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mp3

I want to put a player on a web page and I am using mp3_player (https://github.com/sekrett/mp3_player). I have the plugin installed and everything works, except that the player can't find the path to the file. I have put the file named file.mp3 in the public folder and made the following tags in my code:

> $ <%= mp3_player("/public/file.mp3") %>

The player appears on the page, but when I click play the player says the file is missing. The following routingerror appears in the log:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/public/file.mp3")

What am I doing wrong and is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: The $-sign shouldn't be there but without the code sample wouldn't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write `<%= mp3_player("/file.mp3") %>`.
"Public"  folder is a root folder of your project.

Comment: Do you happen to know, when I click play now it works, but how can I change the name of the file that's playing? The player now displays "Track#1" as name of the file but I want that to be different. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

[kasper375's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1179976/kasper375) suggestion should work. If you're not concerned about pre-HTML5 support, you can also just [wrap the audio file in an `audio` tag](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/mastering-the-html5-audio-property), and the browser will provide an in-browser player for you automatically. `.mp3` and `.ogg` files are typically supported, as I understand.

As a side note, video playback is just as easy with HTML5, with the `video` tag.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good one too. Do you happen to know, when I click play now it works, but how can I change the name of the file that's playing? The player now displays "Track#1" as name of the file but I want that to be different. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Good question - not sure. Did you see this: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp - maybe you could do something as simple as `<source src="some_file.mp3>The name you want displayed</source>` - haven't tried it, but that would make sense in terms of the way most tags work. I would experiment with several different formats until you find something that works.